# SQL CASE on selected column in the same select

Tags: sql, db2

I am constructing a large table where I need to use `CASE` several places in the same select. The problem arises when I need to use an already selected column in a `CASE` in the same select. Example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (B.field_B1 + C.field_C1) > x THEN x ELSE 0 END AS field_1,
       CASE WHEN field_1 > y THEN 'larger' ELSE 'smaller' END AS field 2,
       CASE WHEN field_1 > z THEN 'taller' ELSE 'shorter' END AS field 3
FROM table_A AS A
INNER JOIN table_B as B on A.key_1 = B.KEY_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_C as C on A.key_1 = C.KEY_1
```

The table of interest consists of a few hundred columns and several million rows, so performance is a key issue here. `CROSS APPLY` is not supported in this case, and I would like to avoid `WITH` before the `SELECT` as this is a small part of a large script. Any creative ideas?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer may depend on product used.)

Comment: What about nested case statement?

Comment: A column meaning an already existent `CASE`? Have you considered nesting the `CASE` statements?

Comment: @jarlh I am using IBM DB2.

Comment: Case expressions, not case statements...

Comment: @MUHAMMADTASADDUQALI: I have considered and tried nested case statements, but when this is going to be used for a few hundred columns it is very inefficient. I'm guessing there has to be a much smoother way to do it, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: A derived table perhaps?

Comment: you can always wrap another SELECT around it and nest the queries - in the inner you compute field_1 only, in the outer you split it into three columns

Comment: First off, all you sure the nested CASE statements are a/the problem?  Or are you guessing?  Given that they don't appear to be used in the `WHERE` clause, it seems unlikely they would be the source of a performance issue.

Comment: @Charles: The first 20 columns are pretty straightforward with no nested CASE statements, and had a runtime at about 20 sec. The next 20 columns were made with nested CASE statements, where the runtime was drastically increased for each column, resulting in a total runtime at about 20 min. Since no heavy logic or other changes were applied, I figured the nested CASE statements have to be the bottleneck.